# Recursive Inline with Foreign Fields Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to open django admin for the following models..

```
class FirstModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class SecondModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  firstModel = models.ForeignKey(FirstModel, related_name='secondList')

class ThirdModel(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  secondModel = models.ForeignKey(SecondModel, related_name='thirdList')
```

I am trying to create an admin.py for the following models as follows..

```
class ThirdModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = ThirdModel
  extra = 1

class SecondModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = SecondModel
  inlines = [ThirdModelInline]

class FirstModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [SecondModelInline]

admin.site.register(FirstModel, FirstModelAdmin)
```

I want to be able to edit the SecondModel and ThirdModel as a recursive relation inside FirstModel. But this is not working. I tried to follow this link : [[Model with recursive self relation in Django's admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615351/model-with-recursive-self-relation-in-djangos-admin][1])

[1]: [Model with recursive self relation in Django's admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615351/model-with-recursive-self-relation-in-djangos-admin). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Found a very good library after some websearch. Might help someone else..

https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline

Answer (score 0):

**django-nested-inline** isn't (yet?) supported on latest django releases.

But you could consider using [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin) that is almost the same.